# Get an onchange event of a combo box in a kendo grid

Tags: jquery, combobox, kendo-grid

is it possible to get the onchange event of a combobox with in the kendo grid.. 
The following is my code.

```
var status = [
        {
            "value": 1,
            "text": "New"
        },{
            "value": 2,
            "text": "Reject"
        },{
            "value": 3,
            "text": "Under Review"
        },{
            "value": 4,
            "text": "Approved"
        }];


    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: sourceData,
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: true,
        selectable: "row",
        columns: [
            { field: "firstname", title: "Name",template : displayName},

            { field: "email", title: "Email", },


            { field: "invtn_status", title: "Status" ,  values:status, },

        ],
        editable: true,
    });
```

Now i want to update the status in my database table when the status value is changed(onchange event of the combo box).

Comment: Question has nothing to do with PHP as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the `change` event. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-change).

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  ...
  change: function(e) {
    /* do something */
  }
});
```